# Get the specific username data with Instagram API

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to search and get datas (Profile picture and username )from the exact or specific username with Instagram API. The problem is if I search for example `starwars` it won't show me the official page it shows me this username : `starwars_viii` !!!  Here is my code :

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&client_id=[CLIENT ID]&count=1
```

- I checked and someone said if `count=1` it gives you the exact search
  but it did not work .
- I tried `"usersname"` with quotation it did not
- work ! I removed `count` and same result !

I have to say I am getting datas without authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue by `count = 10` and then filter it with the exact username

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's enough to provide the client id only? According to [their docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search), you should provide an `access_token`:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=jack&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Response:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "username": "jack",
        "first_name": "Jack",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_66_75sq.jpg",
        "id": "66",
        "last_name": "Dorsey"
    },
    {
        "username": "sammyjack",
        "first_name": "Sammy",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_29648_75sq_1294520029.jpg",
        "id": "29648",
        "last_name": "Jack"
    },
    {
        "username": "jacktiddy",
        "first_name": "Jack",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_13096_75sq_1286441317.jpg",
        "id": "13096",
        "last_name": "Tiddy"
    }]
}
```

And as you can see in the response, the first result is the exact username "jack".

Comment: Yes I tried with some websites and they search username without auth and the result is what I am need

Comment: Ok, then can you post the response you receive from Instagram?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you then - but maybe on the site you link they are using an `access_token` by logging in with an instagram account server-side.

Comment: `access_token` requires authentication.